# How can I save key-value options which include key-value options in expl3?

Tags: errors, expl3, latex3, key-value

I have a command which uses a key-value syntax. For example, it includes an image with various options, if desired.

I am using expl3 key-value processing.

I would like to save the key-value settings to a global token list, so that I can reuse them as defaults the next time the command is executed. I couldn't find an obvious way to do this, as I don't want to make the macros the key-value options set global as making them global would complicate things in various ways. All I want is to save the relevant key-values to a global token list so I can reuse them. (I don't care if it is not a token list - that just seemed the obvious choice.)

I can save the booleans and comma-separated lists fine, it seems, but I'm having trouble with token lists which are themselves lists of key-value options. For example, `graphics={<key-value options>}` is used to pass settings to `\includegraphics`. However, I cannot get this to work.

Here is a (comparatively) minimal example, which makes it completely unobvious why on Venus I'm trying to do this, but that's miniaturisation for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_pre_graphics_tl
\tl_new:N \g_pre_img_options_tl
\tl_new:N \g_pre_img_tl
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \pre_key_tl_save:Nn
{
  \tl_if_empty:cF {l_pre_#2_tl}
    {
      \tl_gput_right:No #1 { #2 = }
      \tl_gput_right:NV #1 \c_left_brace_str
      \tl_gput_right:Nv #1 { l_pre_#2_tl }
      \tl_gput_right:NV #1 \c_right_brace_str
      \tl_gput_right:Nn #1 { , }
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_gput_right:Nn {Nv}
% includegraphics bit courtesy of egreg (chat 2015-01-08)
\cs_new:Npn \pre_includegraphics:nn #1 #2
 {
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pre_includegraphics:nn { VV }
\keys_define:nn { pre / img }
{
  graphics .tl_set:N = \l_pre_graphics_tl,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \incimg { o m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \tl_if_empty:NF \g_pre_img_options_tl
    {
      \keys_set:nV { pre / img } \g_pre_img_options_tl
    }
    \IfValueT{#1}{ \keys_set:nn { pre / img } { #1 } }
    \pre_key_tl_save:Nn \g_pre_img_options_tl { graphics }
    \tl_set:Nn \g_pre_img_tl { #2 }
    \pre_includegraphics:VV \l_pre_graphics_tl \g_pre_img_tl
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\incimg[
  graphics={width=\textwidth},
]{example-image-a}
\incimg[
  graphics={width=\textwidth},
]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

The error message has suggested I ask a human for help, so here I am ....

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/misplaced-equals-sign"
! 
! Misplaced equals sign in key-value input 194
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.194 ]{example-image-a}

? h
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''                                                                                              
| LaTeX is attempting to parse some key-value input but found two equals signs                                                                
| not separated by a comma.                                                                                                                   
|...............................................                                                                                              
? h                                                                                                                                           
Sorry, I already gave what help I could...                                                                                                    
Maybe you should try asking a human?                                                                                                          
An error might have occurred before I noticed any problems.                                                                                   
``If all else fails, read the instructions.''                                                                                                 

?
```

If I show the token list before trying to use it, I get

```
> \g_pre_img_options_tl=graphics={width=\textwidth },.
```

which suggests to my simple-mind that I need to somehow include curly brackets around the list. However, my attempts to do this have so far been unsuccessful. Either LaTeX looks for something which isn't meant to be a key (e.g. `\g_pre_img_options`) or the brackets just evaporate.

Comment: I think that the token list should be converted to a string first. I've done similar things with `\prop` lists, where `foo=bar` was possible and feeded as new input to  `\keys_set:nn`

Comment: `\tl_gput_right:NV #1 \c_left_brace_str` doesn't put a `{` with catcode 1.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do. You just want to use `\incimg[<options>]{foo} \incimg{baz}` and ensure that the second one uses the same options as the first one? Or there's something more. If that's the case, it's easy, but I imagine there's something more.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you very much! That works, I think :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't entirely understand what you are trying to achieve, and whatever I'm guessing, I don't think I would do it the same way, but, in any case, here's a change that makes that document compile.

```
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \pre_key_tl_save:Nn
{
  \tl_if_empty:cF {l_cfr_#2_tl}
    {
      \tl_gput_right:No #1 { #2 = }
      \tl_gput_right:NV #1 \c_left_brace_str
      \tl_gput_right:Nv #1 { l_pre_#2_tl }
      \tl_gput_right:NV #1 \c_right_brace_str
      \tl_gput_right:Nn #1 { , }
    }
}
```

This seems wrong, even if I don't understand that clearly, that's, for one, overcomplicating the issue with many different parts, and also, the fact that you cannot actually do that (adding `\c_left_brace_str` is not adding an opening group catcode 1 `{` but an catcode “other”, similar to `\string{`). It's simpler with a plain `x` argument, with the correct `\exp_not:*`.

```
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \pre_key_tl_save:Nn
 {
  \tl_if_empty:cF {l_cfr_#2_tl}
   {
    \tl_gput_right:Nx #1 { #2 = { \exp_not:v { l_pre_#2_tl } } , }
   }
 }
```

With this change it at least compiles, but I don't know if this solves all.

---

You want to add a string, and the value of a macro to another macro. The easiest way to do that is to do all at once with an `x` argument. It's literally doing what you wanted to do, but correct. `\tl_put_right:Nx` expands the second argument in an `\edef`, that is, it expands *everything*, so you only need to stop at the precise moment that you want. After substituting arguments you end with

```
\tl_gput_right:Nx \g_pre_img_options_tl { graphics = { \exp_not:v { l_pre_grahpics_tl } } , }
```

If you saw `\edef\foo{graphics={foo}}` you understand what the content of `\foo` would be: nothing expands, nor the letters, nor the “others” (“=”), nor the braces `{` and `}`. So the magic is inside `\exp_not:v { l_pre_grahpics_tl }`. Thanks to expl3 arguments that is exactly the same as `\exp_not:V \l_pre_grahpics_tl` which in turn is the same as `\exp_not:n { width=\textwidth }` which just stops the expansion there (`\exp_not:n` is `\unexpanded`).

That way, the line above, after the `x` expansion, ends up being exactly

```
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_pre_img_options_tl { graphics = { width = \textwidth } , }
```

if it wasn't for the `\unexpanded{width=\textwidth}` TeX might have tried to expand `\textwidth` as with any other macro, which (not sure right now) might have been expanded to `\dimen <number>` and, in general, we don't want that expansion to happen.

Sorry, but anyone is free to edit this answer, which is anything but perfect.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest :) The `\something:x { ... \exp_not:v { ... } }` pattern (whether `:v`: or whatever) works very nicely for most expansion problems along these lines.

Comment: @WillRobertson I just changed that, I don't understand other parts of the code, nor have I really thought about wether `\tl_if_empty:cF` or `\tl_gput_right:Nx` are the tools for that job. But yes, the `\something:x { .. \exp_not:v { .. } }` is the tool for that expansion problem :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand it, though .... I don't understand how it keeps the group together, I guess. The ` #2 = { ... } ` groups them?

Comment: I'd like to understand it because it seems much better than what I had, but I can't figure out how to adapt it for a clist.

Comment: @cfr An `x` argument is basically passed through an `\edef`, so it looks kind of `\edef\foo{#2={\unexpanded{..}}}` which leaves in your case `graphics={..}` which are all letters or “others” that do not expand, then there are braces with catcode 1 and 2 which do not expand, and the only thing that expands is what's inside the braces. We have there `\exp_not:v { l_pre_graphics_tl }` which (by definition) takes the content of `\l_pre_graphics_tl` and leaves it inside `\unexpanded{..}` so it won't expand further. That way you basically end with `graphics={\unexpanded{width=\textwidth}}`.

Comment: @cfr I can add an explanation in the answer, but I don't see how are you planning to use a clist. In any case, do you have an understanding of how `\edef`, `\noexpand`, `\unexpanded` (and `\expandafter`) work?

Comment: `\edef`, `\noexpand` and `\expandafter`: yes, although I always find it hard to figure out how many in complicated cases. `\unexpanded`: not yet.

Comment: Possibly I have to do the `clist` the way I was doing it before. I asked about the token list because that was the one I couldn't get to work as it is the one with the further key-values complication. The `clist` does work, even it it is ugly. At least, it compiles.

Comment: @cfr `\unexpanded{..}` is basically `\noexpand` but for all the tokens inside the braces at once.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you! And my `clist` works fine when I don't forget a comma. This is very nice - much appreciated. I'm sure my code would give you nightmares.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I don't see a lot of clarity, but if it works, it's okay :) By the way, why `\tl_if_empty:cF`? Don't you want to overwrite even if it's not empty? And, in any case, if you want to overwrite, why `\tl_gput_right:Nx`  and not `\tl_gset:Nx` directly? In any case, I edited the answer, to try to clarify a bit, but I don't think it's really clear, my explanation leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: If it is empty, there's nothing to use to overwrite. I wasn't sure if `key=,` was the same as not setting the key, but I thought not. So I wanted to add `key=<value of local variable>` to the global variable, if the local variable is not empty rather than possibly adding `key=,` to the global variable. Sorry, I just realised that I was not quick enough editing the mistake in my example. Either `cfr` had to be `pre` or `pre` has to be `cfr`.

Comment: If I use `\tl_gset:Nx`, I'll overwrite `\g_pre_img_options_tl`. I want to add to that as it is collecting the key-value pairs. Otherwise, only the last one would get saved. In the MWE, that wouldn't make any difference, of course, but I obviously didn't realise that since I was adding a key-value pair bit-by-bit, when it would matter.